# Delicious.com (crumb trail) style tag filter bar

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have a suggestion which I feel would improve the tag searching on the 3 sites, *and allow you to combine tags without the search box*. The UI I have in mind is 'borrowed' from Delicious and is basically a crumb trail that you can click and add tags into. I'm sure they took it from another source however, and isn't their own creation. For a demo try [here](http://delicious.com/tag/jquery+css).

This could sit underneath tab bar (stats,newest,hotest etc.) fairly easily.

[image: Tags]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're browsing about with a brolly on the site, you can click on the tags and traverse them, adding them along the way for a finer granularity.

It would be nice to also have the ability to remove it from a trail so you can adjust as you go along to see what questions appear with what tag combination.

> [image: Star City man attacks tag trail]

Back button wouldn't help really if you want to nix the second of a list of four or seven without backtracking and traversing the tree manually.

Comment: What's a brolly? And please don't answer if it's a burly guy with a bow; i'm already more than a bit worried by your strange computer techniques.

Comment: A brolly is an umbrella. Because you're walking in a rain of tags.